# Better indentation and navigation in assembly source code

Tags: indentation, navigation

When I write C or Java code it's extremely regular, but with assembly (`asm-mode`), it's so disorganized.

I'm using `auto-complete` and `yasnippet`.  I created snippets and am using them, but the code organization and indentation are disorganized.

What package(s) would help me:

- easily indent code and comments properly, so that I can see what each piece of code is doing;
- navigate that large mass of code, so I can easily jump between pieces of code?

Comment: Please try to make your question more specific. For example: what do you think `asm-mode` should do, but does not? (What features are missing?)

Comment: The [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AssemblyProgramming) has a few options listed for assembly.  But please edit your question to be more specific about the problem and what you've done so far.  "Any useful package" covers a lot of ground.

Comment: Why close this question? Making indentation works (`asm-mode` behaves differently to everything else) and configuring a decent environment (jump around, code completion) is a valid concert.

Comment: For users who wanted this question reopened, please see [this meta discussion](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233/reopen-this-package-recommendation-question).  Please help to clean up the question and clarify it, or else it stands a non-trivial chance that other users will vote to close it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the built-in `asm-mode`. It gives you syntax highlighting for any assembly languages. `gas-mode` does not do that and is not usable with AT&T syntax.

If you want to set indentation for `asm-mode`, note that you cannot use `tab-width` but `tab-stop-list` that specifies spaces that 1 tab, 2 tabs, 3 tabs... can display:

```
(setq tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60
                      64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92 96 100 104 108 112
                      116 120))
```

The above example means that the fist tab has 4 spaces, 2nd tab (next to the first tab) has 8 spaces, 3rd tab (next to the second tab) has 12 spaces... and so on.

You can also generate the list like this:

```
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 60 2))
```

`number-sequence` generates a list of number, with starting number `2` (the first argument) upto `60` (the second argument), each number differs by `2` to the number next to it. And remember to bind `newline-and-indent` to RET, so Emacs automatically indents for you.

If you want to jump around, use Ctags like this:

```
ctags -e -R
```

`-e` means generate tag database to be used by Emacs.
`-R` means recursively generate tags for files in sub-directories from project root.

After that, you can use `helm-etags-select` to jump around or another `etags` client in Emacs if you don't use Helm.

**EDIT**: Here is a sample setup:

```
(require 'asm-mode)
(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (setq indent-tabs-mode nil) ; use spaces to indent
                           (electric-indent-mode -1) ; indentation in asm-mode is annoying
                           (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 60 2))))

(define-key asm-mode-map (kbd "<ret>") 'newline-and-indent)
(define-key asm-mode-map (kbd "M-.") 'helm-etags-select)
```

You can also have basic completion with `company-complete` when pressing `S-TAB`:

```
(define-key asm-mode-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'company-complete)
```

You can use `<tab>` to trigger completion because both `<tab>` and `M-i` run the same command `tab-to-tab-stop` that inserts spaces or tabs depends on your setting of `indent-tabs-mode`. The nice thing with `company-mode` is that you get a brief description of currently highlighted candidate in the minibuffer, if available. For example, if you have a definition like this:

```
KeyStrokes  word    0
```

When you move the cursor to `KeyStrokes` candidate, it prints `word    0` in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 3):

You might try Gas Mode. It should help you with your issue.

http://www.emacswiki.org/GasMode